# Amazon Alexa doesn't open the skill developed by me( on the device)

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have a problem with Amazon Alexa.
I have started to develop a small skill in Alexa Developer Console.

Everything works perfectly when I test it in that console, but when I tell to Alexa device to open my skill. It tell me "I don't know about that".

I don't understand why, the email address is the same for the Developer Console and for the device. I'm sure that the invocation is correct. I tried to disable and enable the skill from the AlexaApp, but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be an internal recognition issue from the invocation name.

What I recommend you to do:

1. Change the invocation name by something very simple ex: `Test four`
2. Save the model and Build the model
3. Try `open Test four` in the developer console
4. Try `open Test four` on the device

If `open Test four` doesn't work on the device, relogin on the Alexa app with the same email as the developer console and resync the device. Make sure the app is enabled.

If it work with `test four` it means that the invocation name you choosed previously is not properly recognized by Alexa. You should keep it as simple as possible or ask the support to improve the recognition of it.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I found the problem. I don't know why( maybe the amazonians added some new lines of code) but before, Alexa recognized the invocation of the skill. In the current situation, Alexa doesn't recognize that word( which is a city from my country). I changed the invocation name.. I used pure english, not a city name pronounciated in another language. Everything is fine again!